What is initiative?
OK, actually we all know what initiative is, but really? Can we give a clear objective definition (maybe based on game-theoretic foundations, or the shape of the variant tree) which a computer can implement, or is initiative just in the eye of the beholder?
My nebulous idea is that if side A has many good moves but side B only forced ones this indicates A has the initiative, and Wiki seems to go along those lines too. Do you have a better definition (since the Wiki article is not formalized enough for my taste)?

The initiative in chess isn't just a "vibe" or something subjective—it can be defined in an objective way, though it gets a bit tricky when you try to formalize it for a computer. Initiative refers to the advantage of making threats that force your opponent to respond in a defensive way, limiting their own options. In game theory terms, the player with the initiative often has a more dominant position on the decision tree (aka the variant tree), where they can choose from multiple reasonable moves while the opponent has fewer "good" choices—often forced ones to avoid immediate loss of material or positional disaster.
Your idea aligns well with the concept of initiative. When one side (let’s say A) has several moves that maintain or increase their pressure on the opponent, and side B is mostly reacting, side A has the initiative. Computers could technically measure this by analyzing the difference in move options between both sides—if one side has significantly more favorable moves than the other, it suggests that they’re driving the game.
To boil it down, initiative could be described as the situation where one player’s choices are largely proactive (many strong moves), and the other player is mostly reactive (limited to defensive or forced moves). And yes, this is something computers can evaluate, especially when looking at who’s forcing the action and dictating the pace of the game.
So, while it’s not just in the eye of the beholder, quantifying it for machines can get complicated, since it’s about pressure and momentum, not just material or direct threats.
